# Как вывести информацию в таблице по неделям и дням

Tags: angularjs

Здравствуйте! Как вывести информацию в таблицу понедельно и отдельно за каждый день с помощью angularjs. Т.е. нажимая например на "След. день/неделя" таблица выводила следующую неделю или день. 
Прогуглил целый день и не нашел информацию как можно делать итерацию над датой в случае дня.

```
public class Game
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } 

    public virtual ICollection<Gamer> Gamers { get; set; }
    public Game()
    {
        Gamers = new List<Gamer>();
    }
}
public class Gamer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int MaxScore { get; set; }
    public DateTime GamerDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Game> Games { get; set; }
    public Gamer()
    {
        Games = new List<Game>();
    }
}
public class LeaderBordContext : DbContext
{

    public DbSet<Gamer> Gamers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Game> Games { get; set; }

    public LeaderBordContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Напишите данные пример данных, которые хотите вывести и желаемый вывод.

Comment: @MrFylypenko Есть модель один-ко-многим. Мне надо вывести данные по геймеру в разрезе игры за день,неделю.  Биндинг на стороне клиента. За день я примерно пониманию. Получаем текущую дату и фильтруем по этой дате. А как быть с неделей?

Comment: Примеров постраничного вывода в интернете очень много, и за разные промежутки. Так и не понятно, как должен выглядеть желаемый результат Ваших данных понедельно и в чем заключается трудность?

Comment: Не нашел я пример вывода за день, неделю. Буду признателен если дадите ссылку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример кода постраничного вывода, нужно только добавить данные, которые хотите выводить, в идеале запрашивать данные от сервера при клике на кнопку. Использован javascript Date api:

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).
controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.todayTime = new Date().getTime();

  //Текущая дата
  $scope.currentDay = new Date();

  //От текущей даты отнимаем день
  $scope.previosDay = function() {
    $scope.currentDay = new Date($scope.currentDay.getTime() - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  }

  //К текущей дате добавляем день
  $scope.nextDay = function() {
    $scope.currentDay = new Date($scope.currentDay.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  }


  //Берем понедельник текущей недели
  $scope.currentWeek = new Date($scope.todayTime - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) * (new Date().getDay() - 1));

  //У текущей недели отнимаем неделю
  $scope.previosWeek = function() {
    $scope.currentWeek = new Date($scope.currentWeek.getTime() - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7));
  }

  //К текущей неделе прибавляем неделю
  $scope.nextWeek = function() {
    $scope.currentWeek = new Date($scope.currentWeek.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7));
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script text="text/javascript">
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div> День: {{currentDay | date:' yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z EEEE '}} </div>
    <div>
      <button ng-click="previosDay()"> Предыдущий день</button>
      <button ng-click="nextDay()"> Следующий день</button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div> Неделя:{{currentWeek | date:' yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z EEEE '}} </div>
    <div>
      <button ng-click="previosWeek()"> Предыдущая неделя </button>
      <button ng-click="nextWeek()"> Следующая неделя </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```